# Determining the direction of a significant spearman's rho correlation

Tags: r, spss

I asked the following question over on stackexchange https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272657/determining-the-direction-of-a-significant-spearmans-rho-correlation - someone pointed me in the direction of this site as I am using spss, so if anyone had any advice that would be much appreciated.

*I have conducted Spearman's Rho tests with two ordinal variables (one with 4 possible answers and the other with 6). I have obtained a statistically significant correlation between the two. My question is, how can I graphically (or some other way) determine which answer of each correlate together - as a scatterplot would not work with my data (since it is not scale).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fluctuation plot is often a good way to look at the distribution of pairs of categorical variables.  There is a custom dialog available for this if you don't want to figure out the GPL code.  It is available from the Community site, but if you can't find it, send me an email (jkpeck@gmail.com), and I'll send it to you.